# Wrong upload directory of upload field

Tags: matrix, file-uploads

I have a Matrix upload field which doesn't show the correct upload folder.

And when I want to upload an image into that wrong folder I get the error: File aready exists. But that is not true.

It also doesn't show anything when I switch to thumbnail view.

And I'm not able to paginate trough the upload files in the upload modal window.

I disabled the cache, there is no path error. What else could this be? When I sync the folder in upload references, there is no error.

How would you debug this?

Comment: Does a standard file upload field in the same channel work as expected?

Comment: Yes it does. So It must be a Matrix issue?

Comment: I'd guess, yeah. If you switch to a different upload directory does it work? Or do all file uploads fail in your Matrix field? Are you running the current versions of Matrix and EE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I guess I found the error (sort of).

1. I updated everything. Now the correct folder shows up, the
   thumbnails work and so on. So there was just something weird going
   on from this old install.
2. The duplicated file problem seems to be a filename character problem. There where spaces and dots in the filename which caused the issue. Apparently these characters are not allowed but eecms doesn't say so.

Is there somewhere a setting or filename to replace irregular characters from a file during upload? Or is there a list which characters are allowed or not or is this a server environment thing?

Comment: Addition: when uploading a file with a dot in the filename. Eecms throws an error (File Already Exists). And then proposes to add underscores before some dots. I don't understand this.